# Default light color scheme from Intellij Idea for Sublime Text 3

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext3, color-scheme

I would like to use the same color scheme (syntax highlighting scheme) in Sublime Text 3 as the one used by default in Intellij Idea (the light one).

What I tried so far:

1. I tried to find an Intellij color scheme at https://packagecontrol.io. I was only able to find a dark Intellij scheme.
2. I tried to export a color scheme from Intellij Idea: File -> Export Settings -> leaving "Code Style (schemes)" and "Look and Feel" checked. This exported two .xml files, both almost empty, and can only be used for Inttelij Idea itself.
3. Googling around. I found a Monakai Theme from Sublime Text 3 for Intellij, but not the other way round.

I will greately appreciate your help.